# How to react to a friend who contacts me after long time intervals but does not respond after I reply and keeps the attitude for multiple times

Tags: friends, intention

**Background:** I have a particular friend with whom I was in the same school and class for primary and high schools. So we know each other since like childhood. We are not closest friends but used to meet four times or so in a month until last two years. No apparent reason for not meeting anymore as far as I know. I guess it's merely because we are more occupied with other things like our jobs.

**Problem:** The thing is, she texts me once or twice in a month asking how I am and how it's going, I reply and try to chat with her since nothing absurd has happened between us before these texts, but she does not reply afterwards. That would be nothing weird if this hadn't happened like five times or so. So the last two times I have offered to meet up as the first response, thinking she wants to chat but over the phone doesn't work good for her, but she postpones and I remind her and she postpones again.

**Question:** How could I learn the motivation behind it when she is not texting back? Calling her and asking is the only option I see but I don't know how to put it into words in a way that projects I mean to keep in touch with her but this attitude doesn't make sense to me so I feel kind of frustrated. I mean I can't just ask why she is avoiding me while she is the one who makes contact in the first place, because it feels kind of overkill and blaming since I actually would like to keep in touch and meet her.

Comment: I'm sorry but we can't read minds. There's no way for us to tell you what this person is thinking. As such, this isn't really a question we can answer. If you'd like to know how to continue to interact with this person, please [edit] your question to focus on this and to explain your goals - do you want to maintain contact? do you want to ignore it? do you want to make her stop? What is it that you want from us?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out,I tried to clarify what I want to get out of the situation by editing. It's very frustrating what she does but I guess she means well and I'm trying to find a way out without letting my  frustration loose on her because she is cool actually aside from this particular behaviour and maybe there is a logical explanation behind it.

Comment: That does sound frustrating. Instead of asking about motivation, are you perhaps looking to confront her about it or wanting to know how to bring it up? As @Catija mentioned, it'll help us answer the question.